# How to use Angular 6+ Form Builder Validator?

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I am trying to use this Angular 6+ form directive validator: [CheckboxRequiredValidator](https://angular.io/api/forms/CheckboxRequiredValidator).  I do not understand how to use it.  The form should not be valid until the checkbox is checked.

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="DeleteForm" (ngSubmit)="deleteEmployee(DeleteForm)">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- New Password -->
    <div class="row mt-2 justify-content-center">
      <div class="col">
        <span>Delete</span>
        <br />
        <kendo-switch formControlName="DeleteInd" [onLabel]="'Yes'" [offLabel]="'No'" required >
        </kendo-switch>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Submit -->
    <div class="row mt-2 justify-content-center">
      <div class="col">
        <button kendoButton [disabled]="!DeleteForm.valid" [primary]="true" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**TypeScript**

```
import {
  FormGroup,
  FormBuilder
} from '@angular/forms';

public DeleteForm: FormGroup;

constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
) {
    this.DeleteForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    DeleteInd: false,
    EmployeeID: 999,
    TerminateDate: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
  }, {
    validator: CheckboxRequiredValidator     // this is wrong
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working solution I have written:

**TypeScript**

```
this.DeleteForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  DeleteInd: false,
  EmployeeID: this.EmployeeID,
  TerminateDate: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
}, {
    validator: [
      this.checkDeleteInd,
    ]
  });

checkDeleteInd(group: FormGroup) {
    let DeleteInd = group.controls.DeleteInd.value;

    return DeleteInd === false ? { DeleteIndFalse: true } : null;
}
```

The checkbox (kendo switch) must be true for the form to be valid.  I was just hoping for a simpler solution to use `CheckboxRequiredValidator` somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
import {
  FormGroup,
  FormBuilder,
  Validators 
} from '@angular/forms';

public DeleteForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.DeleteForm = this.formBuilder.group({
     ...
    deleteInd: [false, Validators.required]
});
```

See for more information the angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms
ctrl + f and enter validation. There you should find necessary info.

best regards,

Sagat

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is using angular template driven validation as below..

**HTML**

```
<form name="form" #deleteform="ngForm">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- New Password -->
    <div class="row mt-2 justify-content-center">
      <div class="col">
        <span>Delete</span>
        <br />
        <kendo-switch name="deleteind" #deleteind="ngModel" [onLabel]="'Yes' [offLabel]="'No'" [(ngModel)]="deleteInd" required >
        </kendo-switch>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Submit -->
    <div class="row mt-2 justify-content-center">
      <div class="col">
        <button kendoButton [disabled]="!deleteform.valid" [primary]="true" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**TypeScript**

```
import { NgForm, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@ViewChild('deleteform') deleteForm: NgForm;

deleteInd: boolean = false;

constructor(){
};
```

Please mind if your using ngModels with form validations you must give a name to each inputs inside the form..

Find more about template-driven forms validations :- https://angular.io/guide/form-validation